# How can I get category ID by category name?

Tags: categories, terms

I have a few categories with the same name [some of them are sub-categories]. And I want to get an array of ID's for certain cattegory name.
I tried this:

```
 $term = get_term_by('name', $cat_name, 'category');
```

but it seems that `get_term_by()` returns only the first term that match the query.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/), which uses `WP_Term_Query` under the hood. For a full list of all the available parameters check out the documentation for [`WP_Term_Query::__construct`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/)

```php
// Get term *IDs* with name that *matches* "my_name"
$term_ids = get_terms([
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'name' => 'my_name',
    'hide_empty' => false,
]);

// Get term *objects* with name that *matches* "my_name"
$terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'name' => 'my_name',
    'hide_empty' => false,
]);

// Get term *objects* with name that *contains* "my_name"
$terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'name__like' => 'my_name',
    'hide_empty' => false,
]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Before your answer I did: `$id = array();
  $args = array(   
   'hide_empty'               => 0,
    );
  
  $categories = get_categories( $args );
  
  foreach($categories as $c){
   if ($c->name == $cat_name){
    $id[] = $c->term_id;
   }
  }`

Answer (score 8):

`get_cat_ID( $cat_name )` can do the trick! Example:

```
<?php
     $category_id = get_cat_ID('Category Name');
     $q = 'cat=' . $category_id;
     query_posts($q);
     if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

     the_content();

     endwhile; endif;
?>
```

[MORE Detail!](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID)